# Repeat begin and end of word using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion

I need to write a Java void method that repeats "comp" at the beginning of "computing" and "ting" at the end, n number of times, using recursion. The only parameter in the method is int n.

Output example:

n = 3
compcompcomputingtingting

n = 2
compcomputingting

n = 1
computing

I have no idea how to do this when you can only pass n every time.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  please take some time to read [ask]. If you don't show some effort, don't expect much help.  Sorry/

Comment: Put some effort

Comment: why do u need recursion for this, u can use a small for loop too, to get the desired output

Comment: Think about a recurrence relation.  How can you form the output for `n` using the output for `n - 1`?  What is your base case?

Comment: Do you have an idea, how it would look like for n = 0? Is the advice, to return a String or just to print on screen? [mcve] Don't you even have a method stub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function inside itself. Think of recurrence relations. As long as `n>0` you need to call the function inside itself with decreasing n. So call `f(3) f(2) f(1)` how do you do it? `f (n-1)` Your stopping condition is when `n==0` Then you also need to print a single `u`and continue with `tingtingting` So your function is like this in pseudocode:

```
f(n):
  if (n > 0)
    print("comp");
    f(n-1);
  if (n = 0)
    print("u");
```

--Don't expect a full code answer as this is obviously a homework question. You can add the ting ting ting part, just trace it in your head, what is going on?

Comment: how would you return to the original value of n after you get n = 0?

Comment: The value of n outside your call to function will not be affected as java primitive types are pass by value, meaning only the value of n is passed to the function and assigned to an internal variable: n, in the scope of function.

Answer (score 0):

I only know how to do it 9 times:

```
-> String s = "u"; for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) { s="comp" + s + "ting"; println (s); }
|  Modified variable s of type String with initial value "u"
|    Update overwrote variable s
computing
compcomputingting
compcompcomputingtingting
compcompcompcomputingtingtingting
compcompcompcompcomputingtingtingtingting
compcompcompcompcompcomputingtingtingtingtingting
compcompcompcompcompcompcomputingtingtingtingtingtingting
compcompcompcompcompcompcompcomputingtingtingtingtingtingtingting
compcompcompcompcompcompcompcompcomputingtingtingtingtingtingtingtingting
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer to your question!

```
public static void repeat(String beg, String mid, String end, int n) {
    String result="";
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        result=result+beg;
    }
    result=result+mid;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        result=result+end;
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The Reason I created this as a method, is because, if you ever wanted to do something like this again, all you have to do is call it like this:

**Input:**

```
repeat("comp", "u", "ting", 4);
```

**Output:**

```
compcompcompcomputingtingtingting
```

**Input:**

```
repeat("lama", "", "word", 3);
```

**Output:**

```
lamalamalamawordwordword
```

Now, you can use this for any stance, and always get the desired output...

Comment: 1. Don't just do someone's assignment for them. 2. This isn't even a recursive solution.

Comment: Well they asked for help and I gave it to them, but only answering half of it, doesn;t help them either...

Comment: And yes it it, cause you are getting the required resonce

Comment: Help != Do it for me.

Comment: What?  Why the comment "Help != Do it for me."???

Comment: @rgettman your code doesn't even make any sence!  Like mine is outlined, and you can see exactly whats going on, in yours someone can't learn from the usage of it, whereas someone looks at mine, knows what exactly i going on, and can learn from it...